# Integrating factors for inexact and linear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am coursing differential equations and recently encountered with the concept of integrating factors. I have seen them to solve two types of ODEs: inexact and linear.
A linear equation is an ODE in the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y = q(y)$$
the integrating factor ends up being:
$$u(x) = e^{\int p(x)dx}$$
so that the equation comes to:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(uy) = q(x)u(x)$$
the equation can now be solved if $\int q(x)u(x)dx$ can be computed.

An inexact equation is an equation in the form $$A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy=0$$, where 
$$A_y \ne B_x$$
(i.e. $Adx+Bdy$ is not an exact differential)

The integrating factor for these equations (I will call it $\mu$ for inexact equations) is a function such that 
$$(\mu A)_y = (\mu B)_x$$
Expanding,
$$\mu A_y +  \mu_y A = \mu B_x +  \mu_x A$$
I have read the Wikipedia article, which says that to solve this equation where $\mu = \mu (x,y)$ requires partial differential equations, but if $\mu = \mu(x)$ or $\mu = \mu(y)$, then there is a straightforward formula for both, in terms of $A$ and $B$ (and their partial derivatives, respectively). But here is the important part: it says

"[...]  *in which case we only need to find  $\mu$  with a first-order linear differential equation or a separable differential equation* [...]"

Does this mean that this method can only be used for linear ODEs? In that case, I think the first method is way faster.

[Article mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is referring to how to **find** $\mu$, not the form of the original D.E.

Consider the equation you quote:-$$\mu A_y +  \mu_y A = \mu B_x +  \mu_x A$$

If $\mu = \mu(x)$ then this equation becomes
$$\mu A_y  = \mu B_x +  \mu_x A$$
$$\mu (A_y - B_x) =  \mu_x A$$
This is the 'straightforward equation' referred to in the article.

Comment: Alright. I was really confused and thought for a moment that the phrase meant that the method would be actually "useless" and that the fact that the factor was a single-variable function implied that  the differential equation was linear or separable. This was really useful. Thanks!